# Usercontrol event Handler

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have 2 usercontrol as the following (webheader , webfooter) in C#

```
   <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="webheader.ascx.cs"     Inherits="WebUserControls.webheader" %>
   <p>
    <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add" onclick="btnAdd_Click" />

    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

    <asp:Button ID="btnEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit" />

    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

    <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" />

  </p>


  <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="webFooters.ascx.cs"      Inherits="WebUserControls.webFooters" %>
  <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
  <br />
  <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
  <br />
  <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
  <br />
  <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
  <br />
  <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
   <p>
    &nbsp;</p>
```

i have 3 buttons in the usercontrol webheader i want to call 3 different methods in the webfooters each button called different method how can i handle that since i put the 2 usercontrol on a page

Answer (score 0):

You can do it very easily with the help of Events and Delegates.

Expose events from WebHeader and subscribe to it in the content page. Make the methods in WebFooter public which you want to call on WebHeader Click. Once the button is clicked call the appropiate method of WebFooter

```
//pseudo code

//WebHeader
public delegate void Button1Clicked(object[] args);
//raise this event when the button is clicked
public event Button1Clicked buttonClicked;

//WebFooter
public void Method1(object[] params); //for button 1 click



//In content page which holds both header and footer control
WebHeader.Button1Clicked+= new WebHeader.Button1Clicked (HandleClick);

public void HandleClick(object[] params)
{
    WebFooter.Method2(params);
}
```

See following example for more clarity http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article201.aspx

Comment: i will try it and i will let you know the result

Comment: @RabihGebara : Mark the answer as correct to close it, if it solved your query. Thanks